# Get a list of all site collections including Office 365 Groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups

How can I get a list of all site collections in my SharePoint Online farm including ones for Office 365 Groups?

I've ran into problems when creating a new site collection where I'm unaware that an Office 365 group already exists with the same url.  The cause is not always obvious because sometimes I get an error where it says that the site already exists and other times I get an access denied error even though I am a Global Admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PowerShell based solution:**

Download SharePoint Online Management Shell

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588

Run the commands below to get a list of all site collections

```
Connect-SPOService -Url "https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com" 

Get-SPOSite
```

Comment: This is correct, but just to note, this is a new capability of the tool. If you have an older version of the shell, it will only output "regular" site collections. if this happens, install an updated version of the shell.